# "Make it a point to" or "make a point of"?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

Is there any difference between using these expressions?

> She made a point of taking a vacation in Italy.
> She made it a point to take a vacation in Italy.

Answer (score 5):

**Made a point of**

*Meaning ::*

1. you are making something or someone into an important topic/matter.
2. to be certain to do something

> 1. Please don't make a point of Sasha's answer, it was not an urgent matter.
> 2. She made a point of sending thank you notes to everyone who attended her wedding.

**Make a point to**

*Meaning ::*

1. act purposely or intentionally
2. to be certain to do something

> Two women are gossiping over a newcomer.
>   One of them says that he hasn't brought many things along with him. He only has clothes and a few other things.
>
> The other woman replies: "Maybe he's having his stuff sent."
>
> The first one says: "I asked him. Made it a point."

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic phrase is "make a point of doing something" which means "make sure to do something that is important or necessary." In your case, the sentence would be "She made a point of taking a vacation in Italy."

Answer (score 0):

In your case ***made a point of*** seems to be the correct one, which according to the NOAD means:

> **make a point of** make a special and noticeable effort to do (a specified thing): *she made a point of taking a walk each day.*

*Make a point* followed by *infinitive* is a perfectly valid expression. But it's used when you want to make a statement about something. For example:

> "The president made a point to raise those issues tonight making a clear play for..."