# 'make it a point to' or 'make a point to'?

Tags: phrase-usage

According to [this previous post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4974/make-a-point-to-or-make-a-point-of),

**make a point to**:

1. act purposely or intentionally
2. to be certain to do something

However, I can't find any explanations for **make a point to** in dictionaries. Instead, I found **make it a point to** in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20it%20a%20point%20to%20(do%20something)).

Should it be **make a point to** or **make it a point to**? Or they mean the same and are interchangeable?

Comment: I hear it both ways. "You should make a point to see Bela Fleck when he's in town" or "I make it a point to smoke only one cigar at a time." The dummy subject *it* is implicit in the first example. See [conversational deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversational-deletion) on our sister site, English Language & Usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some expressions are carved in stone: there is just one form, and you have to use it exactly, otherwise it might mean something completely different. Others have evolved several variants, and this is one of them. Both of the versions that you have quoted are acceptable.

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20it%20a%20point%20to%2C%20make%20a%20point%20to%2Cmake%20a%20point%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20it%20a%20point%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20point%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20point%20of%3B%2Cc0) shows the relative frequency of the two versions that you quoted and the one that I normally use. Here are typical examples of each usage:
 -

> I **make it a point to** be a nice guy - [Falling for you](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=gvCeAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT54&dq=%22make%20it%20a%20point%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy7fLP97rYAhWJA5oKHfmoB744UBDoAQhBMAU#v=onepage&q=%22make%20it%20a%20point%20to%22&f=false)
>   I did **make a point to** look up his next show and attend it.  - [Happily ever after: a tale of a wedding planner](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=nRLDAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&dq=%22make%20a%20point%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz1KGx-LrYAhWnQpoKHUNbCJo4HhDoAQgkMAA#v=onepage&q=%22make%20a%20point%20to%22&f=false).
>   To help yourself to work more efficiently, **make a point of** going out each lunchtime. - [Freelance fashion designer's handbook](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=-gcjfHX4p2YC&pg=PA88&dq=%22make%20a%20point%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqqIOR9rrYAhUlQZoKHWxwC1E4KBDoAQgkMAA#v=onepage&q=%22make%20a%20point%20of%22&f=false)